# Fedora 37 and NVIDIA drivers problem

Tags: fedora, drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers, bugs

I installed Fedora on a Rog Strix Laptop following [this guide for 2021 laptops](https://asus-linux.org/wiki/fedora-guide/). I also enabled experimental fractional scaling, but then I disabled it for good. Since then I experienced two problems:

- Gestures with three fingers stopped working (they were fine before installing Fedora and NVIDIA drivers). **This problem still persists!**
- In the past Fedora would bug: the Rog control center stopped working and the power and shutdown options in gnome would disappear. I was able to make this issue disappear by removing the package: `xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power`, that was installed during the installation of NVIDIA proprietary drivers. (Also: the presence of this package would cause the fan of the laptop to spin up without any particular reason, at random)

*My question is:* **what does `xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power` do?**

I experienced no issues without it.. Why was it installed in the first place? I have read online that is a *weak dependency* for the NVIDIA drivers, is it true? Why was it causing bugs in Fedora/Gnome? Is this related with the *gestures not working* problem? Could it have something to do with my enabling of experimental fractional scaling? I have enabled it following [this guide](https://www.omglinux.com/how-to-enable-fractional-scaling-fedora/), then I disabled it, and then when I tried to enabled it again it just does nothing! I don't know if this could have something to do with the NVIDIA drivers problem.

---

**EDIT:** I figured out part of the problem: apparently I am not currently using Wayland anymore! This explains the missing functionalities of gestures.. But when I installed Fedora 37 Wayland was working correctly.. Why did the install of NVIDIA drivers cause my laptop to switch to x11? NVIDIA should support Wayland by now, right?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov why did you commented a link to that forum? This is hardly a relevant comment for my question. Also I am not a developer

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I appriciate your help man! But maybe next time you should trow with the link a snippet of text like: "you should check out this forum", or "I think your question belongs here". Just posting a link is a little bit unclear and unhelpful in my opinion. No need to get passive aggressive about it